# Cannot find limit

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I was solving an improper integral, but I am stuck in here
$$\lim_{b\rightarrow +\infty} b^{1-\theta} $$ could you write, please, how to solve this limit?

Thank you

Comment: What is that improper integral then?

Comment: @user284331
$$\int \limits_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}^{\theta+1}y{\theta}k^{\theta}dy$$   k is assumed to be known. This problem is from Mathematical Statistics, I am trying to find method of moments estimate for theta

Comment: what is $\theta$?

Comment: \theta is an unknown parameter

Comment: @Learningmath Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$\int \limits_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}^{\theta+1}y{\theta}k^{\theta}dy$$

note that

$$\frac{1}{y}^{\theta+1}y{\theta}k^{\theta}\sim \frac{{\theta}k^{\theta}}{y^{\theta}}$$

thus by limit comparison test with $\int \frac{1}{y^{\theta}}$ the integral converges for $\theta >1$

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite it as
$$b^{1-\theta}=e^{(1-\theta)\log(b)}$$
And as $b\to \infty$, $\log(b) \to \infty$.
If $1-\theta<0$, then it will go to $0$.
If $1-\theta =0$, then it will go to $1$.
If $1-\theta >0$, then it will go to $\infty$.